# install peacock, during ./configure missing libraries, but they are actually

Tags: linux, configure

During `./configure` I obtained this error:

```
configure: error: Library requirements (libgnomeui-2.0 >= 2.2.0 libbonoboui-2.0 >= 2.2.0 libglade-2.0 >= 2.0.1 gtksourceview-1.0 >= 0.5.0) not met;
consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if your libraries are in a nonstandard prefix so pkg-config can find them.
```

Which I do not understand. I listed my packages using: `/sbin/ldconfig -p` and from many of them I have:

```
libbonoboui-2.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbonoboui-2.so.0
libbonoboui-2.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbonoboui-2.so
libgnomeui-2.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnomeui-2.so.0
libgnomeui-2.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnomeui-2.so
```

Ideas?

Comment: For libgnomeui and libbonoboui, it requires greater than or equal to 2.2.0 whereas you have 2.0. Also, do you have libgblade and gtksourceview?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the configure script is complaining that you need *all* of those libraries installed, while you only have *some* of them.

Specifically, you already satisfy these two dependencies:

- libgnomeui-2.0 >= 2.2.0
- libbonoboui-2.0 >= 2.2.0

While it seems you still can't satisfy these two:

- libglade-2.0 >= 2.0.1
- gtksourceview-1.0 >= 0.5.0

Try installing the last two and trying that `./configure` command to see if it stops complaining about missing libraries.

If it doesn't, take a look at `config.log` (warning: it's a big and long file and many times it's hard to understand it unless you know a lot about autoconf!) to try to understand which checks the configure script is using that are failing to detect the installed libraries.

Comment: He actually hasn't satisfied the requirement for the first two. They both need later versions than what he has.

Comment: @NasirRiley It's hard to tell whether that's the case, many times the actual version is not really fully encoded in the library filename. Would need to see inside the pkgconfig for those to be sure. But yeah, it's quite possibly not a high enough version for those either!